# Javascript/JQuery/Angular: Use a key to count number of times value occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, loops

I have two JSON files:

```
1) {id:1, location:'Texas'}, {id:2, location:'New York'}

2) {id:1, val:'author'}, {id:1, val:'author'}, {id:1, val:'reviewer'}
```

I want to use the id, to show location and count the number of times id has authored/reviewed in one shot. ( I have only val types - author and reviewer).

Expected output (JSON, HTML or just loop in Javascript/Angular)

```
id:1, location:'Texas', count (for Author): 2, count (for reviewer): 1
```

I also have a bunch of ids to loop against. What might be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: So the ids correlate the json objects between the files? If so, the naive algorithm would nest two for loops.

Comment: yes the Ids are correlated. Ok, will try it out. I was trying to see if I could avoid that. Am going to try the approach suggested below. I will be using the data in angular ng-repeat, so it might make sense to add an extra type jjust for the counts and loop through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reduce to create the result and a forEach to update the counts should be fine.

```
var result = locations.reduce(function(result, item) {
    item.author = 0;
    item.reviewer = 0;
    result[item.id] = item;
    return result;
}, Object.crete(null));
authorReviewers.forEach(functin(obj) {
    result[obj.id][obj.val]++;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Am trying this out. I wasn't aware of reduce before .

Comment: what is the object you are looping against in the second part - forEach against which part. if you have a working example, great. Meanwhile I will try to put an example of what I'm doing as well.

Comment: @LoserCoder - locations would be your object array referencing (json file 1) in your question, while authorReviwers is referencing (json file 2) in your question.